# Why the auto_increment id does not increase one by one, how to set it?

Tags: mysql, primary-key, mariadb

I have a MariaDB Galera Cluster(3 nodes), I set `uid` to increase automatically and be the primary key of the table as

```
 `uid       | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment`. 


 MariaDB [hello_cluster]> select uid from table order by uid limit 10;
    +-----+
    | uid |
    +-----+
    |   3 |
    |   6 |
    |   9 |
    |  12 |
    |  15 |
    |  18 |
    |  21 |
    |  24 |
    |  27 |
    |  30 |
    +-----+
```

I tried the following command, and it does not work

```
 alter table uid AUTO_INCREMENT=1
```

Comment: You're correct. I dug up some more relevant information.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is by design and is reported in [MariaDB Galera Cluster - Known Limitations](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-galera-cluster-known-limitations/):

> Do not rely on auto-increment values to be sequential. Galera uses a mechanism based on autoincrement increment to produce unique non-conflicting sequences, so on every single node *the sequence will have gaps*.

The rational is explained in [Managing Auto Increments with Multi Masters](http://codership.blogspot.com/2009/02/managing-auto-increments-with-multi.html), and is also why the observed auto-increment has the same step as the number of clusters.

> MySQL has system variables auto_increment_increment and auto_increment_offset for managing auto increment 'sequences' in multi master environment. Using these variables, it is possible to set up a multi master replication, where *auto increment sequences in each master node interleave*, and no conflicts should happen in the cluster. No matter which master(s) get the INSERTs.

Even without clusters, it is rarely a "good" idea to rely on auto-increment columns to be dense sequences due to transaction rollbacks and deleted records.

Comment: thanks a lot, I should read those limitations before I setup my own cluster!

Comment: Has this changed since 2014? We're switching over to a  MySQL Galera Cluster and there's questions about how the newer versions handle auto incrementing columns.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue with a mariaDB galera cluster, any changes??

Comment: @robert.bo.roth As of 2020, we still face the behaviour of not sequential auto-increment values.

Answer (score 0):

> wsrep_auto_increment_control= off

will allow you change **auto_increment_increment** and **auto_increment_offset** in mysql. Recommend only in master-slave environment, because in master-master environment there may be chance of accidental conflict with auto increment keys.

Hope this will help someone.