# MariaDB skips some autoincrementing values when using load data local infile

Tags: php, mariadb, load-data-infile

I've encountered a strange thing with MariaDB, and I don't know if this is normal, or I should continue on searching for a bug in my code.

I am creating csv files in batches, each batch containing ~10000 rows of data, then inserting that temporary file into a database table, using the `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`. The table in which I am inserting the data to, has 5 columns in total, the first being an auto incrementing primary key. The other 4 columns are all provided in my local csv file.

The problem that I am encountering, that if I run my script for 10 batches of files, the highest id in my table becomes different then the expected 96.545 (this is the exact amount of lines I am inserting, counted it in PHP, before adding the rows to the csv file). I don't know why is this happening, this is the exact code that I run:

```
function batchAttributeInsert($attributeBatch) {
    global $attributeLines;

    $tmpFileAttributes = DEFAULT_DIR_WHOME . 'cashback/tmp/' . uniqid('tmp.') . '.tmp';
    $tmpFileAttributesHandler = fopen($tmpFileAttributes, 'w');
    
    foreach ($attributeBatch as $productId => $batch) {
         $attributesArray = array();

         foreach ($batch['attributes'] as $Attribute) {
            $attributeList = $Attribute->separate();

            foreach ($attributeList as $attributeData) {
                fputcsv($tmpFileAttributesHandler, array($attributeData['key'], $attributeData['value'], $attributeData['confidence'], $productId), "|", "'");
                $attributeLines++;
            }
         }
    }    
    
    
    fclose($tmpFileAttributesHandler);
    DB('main')->query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" . $tmpFileAttributes . "' INTO TABLE ProductAttributes FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' ENCLOSED BY '\'' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' IGNORE 0 LINES (Attribute, Value, Confidence, products_ProductId)");

    unlink($tmpFileAttributes);
}
```

After I run this script, `$attributeLines` becomes 96.545, and the highest number in the primary key field in the table in turn is: 152.421. If I do a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ProductAttributes` query after the script, MariaDB reports back that there are 96.545 rows in the table.

If I reran the script with the exact same parameters after I have `TRUNCATE`-ed the table, the row count and the inner `$attributeLines` report the same values, but the highest primary key id changes, to a different number in the range of 150.000.

Could someone tell me what happens to the missing auto increment values after this process or why I am getting so inconsistent numbers? Could this be a bug in my script, or I have nothing to worry about?

I am using `Server version: 10.4.19-MariaDB MariaDB Server`.

Comment: Auto increment isn't guaranteed to be sequential. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23022574/why-the-auto-increment-id-does-not-increase-one-by-one-how-to-set-it for an example when it won't be.

Comment: Why do you care?

Comment: @Barmar if there is no bug here, I don't really care - but if this may be some bug, in my code or somewhere, I do want to fix it now, before I move onward and build other things around this code. In your link, the autoincrement is set to 3, because of the master-slave (or master-master replication), but I have my auto increment in the table set to 1.

Comment: What is **probably** happening is that your script is running so rapidly the DB can't keep up and is skipping the AI values ..   Either way .. It should be of no consequence so long as they are unique.

Comment: What kind of bug could it be in your code? You just used a `LOAD DATA INFILE` command, the database does all the work.

Comment: @Zak that's a starting point - if what you say is true, just for testing purposes, a sleep of like 5 seconds between inserting the batches, should theoretically solve the issue, am I right?

Comment: @Adam -- It's worth trying .. But in reality .. If the rows are there .. There's really nothing to worry about.  If you had 100,000 and inserted 95,000 I'd be more worried about the failed inserts than the AI key ..

Comment: okay, tried that out, but the issue is still there, so that is not what is happening - would it be possible, that some of my `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` commands fail, and MariaDB silently retries them until they succeed?